# Which Tooling API Objects can be queried in Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, query, tooling-api

I would like to know which objects I can query in Apex which are not listed in the [SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) but are listed in the [Tooling API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm). Is there a list maintained somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this writing, the following types are available in the `Schema` namespace and can be queried (with one noted exception). These objects are listed in the `Tooling API Developer Guide`, but not in the `SOAP API Developer Guide`:

- `ApexEmailNotification`
- `BrandingSet`
- `BrandingSetProperty`
- `BusProcessFeedbackConfig`
- `DataType`
- `EntityDefinition`
- `EntityParticle`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `EntityDefinitionId`
    - `FieldDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `FieldDefinition`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `EntityDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `FieldSet`

  - **Cannot be queried**
- `IPAddressRange`
- `Publisher`
- `RelationshipDomain`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `RelationshipInfoId`
    - `ChildSobjectId`
    - `ParentSobjectId`
    - `FieldId`
    - `DurableId`
- `RelationshipInfo`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `ChildSobjectId`
    - `FieldId`
    - `DurableId`
- `SearchLayout`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `EntityDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `UserEntityAccess`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `UserId`
    - `DurableId`
- `UserFieldAccess`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on `DurableId`

Any of the above queries which require certain filters will otherwise throw an error message in the below format:

> System.QueryException: MALFORMED_QUERY: EntityParticle: a filter on a reified column is required: [EntityDefinitionId,FieldDefinitionId,DurableId]

---

The following objects are defined in both APIs and can be queried in Apex:

- `ApexClass`
- `ApexComponent`
- `ApexLog`
- `ApexPage`
- `ApexPageInfo`
- `ApexTestQueueItem`
- `ApexTestResult`
- `ApexTestResultLimits`
- `ApexTestRunResult`
- `ApexTestSuite`
- `ApexTrigger`
- `AssignmentRule`
- `AuraDefinition`
- `AuraDefinitionBundle`
- `BriefcaseDefinition`
- `BusinessProcess`
- `ColorDefinition`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `TabDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `CspTrustedSite`
- `CustomHelpMenuSection`
- `CustomHttpHeader`
- `CustomNotificationType`
- `DataIntegrationRecordPurchasePermission`
- `Document`
- `DuplicateJobDefinition`
- `DuplicateJobMatchingRuleDefinition`
- `EmailTemplate`
- `ExternalDataSource`
- `ForecastingDisplayedFamily`
- `FormulaFunction`
- `FormulaFunctionAllowedType`
- `Group`
- `IconDefinition`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `TabDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `MatchingRule`
- `NamedCredential`
- `OwnerChangeOptionInfo`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on one of:

    - `EntityDefinitionId`
    - `DurableId`
- `PermissionSet`
- `PermissionSetGroup`
- `PermissionSetGroupComponent`
- `PermissionSetTabSetting`
- `Profile`
- `RecentlyViewed`
- `RecordType`
- `Scontrol`
- `SiteDetail`

  - Can be queried, but must filter on `DurableId`
- `StaticResource`
- `TabDefinition`
- `TestSuiteMembership`
- `TransactionSecurityPolicy`
- `User`
- `WebLink`

---

As of this writing, the following objects are not available in the `Schema` namespace and cannot be queried:

- `AnimationRule`
- `ApexClassMember`
- `ApexCodeCoverage`
- `ApexCodeCoverageAggregate`
- `ApexComponentMember`
- `ApexExecutionOverlayAction`
- `ApexExecutionOverlayResult`
- `ApexOrgWideCoverage`
- `ApexPageMember`
- `ApexResult`
- `ApexTriggerMember`
- `AutoResponseRule`
- `BusinessProcessDefinition`
- `BusinessProcessFeedback`
- `BusinessProcessGroup`
- `Certificate`
- `CleanDataService`
- `CleanRule`
- `CommunityWorkspacesNode`
- `CompactLayout`
- `CompactLayoutInfo`
- `CompactLayoutItemInfo`
- `ContainerAsyncRequest`
- `CustomApplication`
- `CustomField`
- `CustomFieldMember`
- `CustomObject`
- `CustomTab`
- `DataAssessmentConfigItem`
- `DebugLevel`
- `DeployDetails`
- `EmbeddedServiceBranding`
- `EmbeddedServiceConfig`
- `EmbeddedServiceCustomComponent`
- `EmbeddedServiceCustomization`
- `EmbeddedServiceCustomLabel`
- `EmbeddedServiceFieldService`
- `EmbeddedServiceFlow`
- `EmbeddedServiceFlowConfig`
- `EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent`
- `EmbeddedServiceMenuItem`
- `EmbeddedServiceMenuSettings`
- `EmbeddedServiceQuickAction`
- `EmbeddedServiceResource`
- `EnrichedField`
- `EntityLimit`
- `EventDelivery`
- `EventSubscription`
- `ExternalServiceRegistration`
- `ExternalString`
- `ExternalStringLocalization`
- `ExternalString`
- `FieldMapping`
- `FieldMappingField`
- `FieldMappingRow`
- `FieldRestrictionRule`
- `FlexiPage`
- `Flow`
- `FlowDefinition`
- `FlowElementTestCoverage`
- `FlowTestCoverage`
- `FormulaOperator`
- `GlobalValueSet`
- `GtwyProvPaymentMethodType`
- `HeapDump`
- `HistoryRetentionJob`
- `HomePageComponent`
- `HomePageLayout`
- `InboundNetworkConnection`
- `InboundNetworkConnProperty`
- `Index`
- `IndexField`
- `InstalledSubscriberPackage`
- `InstalledSubscriberPackageVersion`
- `KeywordList`
- `Layout`
- `LightningComponentBundle`
- `LightningComponentResource`
- `LookupFilter`
- `ManagedContentNodeType`
- `ManagedContentType`
- `MarketingAppExtension`
- `MarketingAppExtAssignment`
- `MarketingAppExtActivity`
- `MenuItem`
- `MetadataComponentDependency (Beta)`
- `MetadataContainer`
- `MetadataPackage`
- `MetadataPackageVersion`
- `ModerationRule`
- `MyDomainLog`
- `OperationLog`
- `OpportunitySplitType`
- `OutboundNetworkConnection`
- `OutboundNetworkConnProperty`
- `PackageInstallRequest`
- `PackageUploadRequest`
- `PackageVersionUninstallRequestError`
- `PathAssistant`
- `Package2`
- `Package2Member`
- `Package2Version`
- `Package2VersionCreateRequest`
- `Package2VersionCreateRequestError`
- `PathAssistantStepInfo`
- `PathAssistantStepItem`
- `PermissionDependency`
- `PlatformEventChannel`
- `PlatformEventChannelMember`
- `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`
- `PostTemplate`
- `ProfileLayout`
- `QueryResult`
- `QuickActionDefinition`
- `QuickActionList`
- `QuickActionListItem`
- `RecommendationStrategy`
- `RecordActionDeployment`
- `ReleaseUpdate`
- `RemoteProxy`
- `RestrictionRule (Beta)`
- `SandboxInfo`
- `SandboxProcess`
- `SecurityHealthCheck`
- `SecurityHealthCheckRisks`
- `ServiceFieldDataType`
- `SOQLResult`
- `SourceMember`
- `StandardAction`
- `SubscriberPackage`
- `SubscriberPackageVersion`
- `SubscriberPackageVersionUninstallRequest`
- `SymbolTable`
- `TimeSheetTemplate`
- `TimeSheetTemplateAssignment`
- `TraceFlag`
- `UserCriteria`
- `ValidationRule`
- `WorkflowAlert`
- `WorkflowFieldUpdate`
- `WorkflowOutboundMessage`
- `WorkflowRule`
- `WorkflowTask`
- `WorkSkillRouting`
- `WorkSkillRoutingAttribute`